# Como crear consulta WHERE con varios OR en django?

Tags: python, django-models

Quiero realizar una consulta `WHERE` con varios `OR` en `models.filter()` pero no se como he usado el metodo `extra(where=['...'])` pero creo que es no es la mejor forma para comparar columnas de un mismo modelo siendo este una producto de una relación OnetoOne.

Tengo la tablas o modelos `examen` que se relaciona con `resultado` el cual tiene los campos `primero` , `segundo` , `tercero`, `cuarto` , solo me interesan los exámenes en los que el resultado cambio, solo quiero consultar los que son diferentes entre si en orden consecutivo y su valor no sea None.

El sql es así.

```
SELECT * FROM examen 
JOIN resultado rs on resultado.id = examen.codigo
WHERE 
 (rs.primero != None AND (rs.primero != rs.segundo AND rs.segundo != None))
 OR (rs.segundo != rs.tercero AND rs.tercero != None)
 OR (rs.tercero != rs.cuarto AND rs.cuarto != None)
```

Como podría lograr esto de django, estoy haciendo lo siguiente.

```
models.filter(,,)
      .select_related(,,)
      .extra( where=['resultado__primero' != None,                          
                     'resultado__primero' != 'resultado__segundo',
                     'resultado__segundo' != None])
```

Funciona para la primer validación pero  ¿como agrego el OR ? para las otras 2 validaciones o ¿ cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo ?

Ademas realice lo siguiente:.

```
models.filter(,,)
      .select_related(,,)
      .extra( where=["'resultado__primero' != None                        
                     AND ('resultado__primero' != 'resultado__segundo'
                     OR 'resultado__segundo' != None )"])
```

Funciona pero en Django al parecer este `.extra(where)` sera desatendido y piden que se haga el ticket en https://code.djangoproject.com/query?status=assigned&status=new&keywords=~QuerySet.extra existe una mejor manera de hacerlo, no quiero tener que en meses no tener soporte y seguir haciendo consultas de este forma.

Comment: Está buena la pregunta por que el tipo de consulta es complejo y real. Según lei creo que es necesario utilizar expresiones Q y F para poder consultar por el valor de un campo que se deduce de otro campo del mismo modelo (anexo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491884/django-queryset-filter-by-the-value-of-another-field ). Te ayudaría más si supuiera pero no tengo experiencia con ese tipo de objetos, hasta el momento no me ha sido necesario ocuparlos. Otra pista puede ser utilizar una consulta SQL directamente al ORM como la que colocaste en tu pregunta.